# How can I filter a SQL query in Entity Framework in C#?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm trying to convert this into an async method, but I don't think I'm querying the data properly to do it. What am I missing to:

1. make this cleaner
2. make it async

All the `InventorySelection` is, is a class with the various filter items.

```
private IEnumerable<T_IFS_Inventory> Getquery(T_IFS_InventorySelectDTO InventorySelection)
{
    IEnumerable<T_IFS_Inventory> query = _db.T_IFS_Inventory.AsQueryable();

    if (InventorySelection.SerialNumber != "" && InventorySelection.SerialNumber != null)
    {
        query = query.Where(q => q.SerialNumber == InventorySelection.SerialNumber);
    }
    else
    {
        if (InventorySelection.ScanDateStart != null)
        {
            query = query.Where(q => q.ScanDate >= InventorySelection.ScanDateStart);

            if (InventorySelection.ScanDateEnd != null)
                query = query.Where(q => q.ScanDate <= InventorySelection.ScanDateEnd);
        }

        if (InventorySelection.StatusDateStart != null)
        {
            query = query.Where(q => q.DateStatus >= InventorySelection.StatusDateStart);

            if (InventorySelection.StatusDateEnd != null)
                query = query.Where(q => q.DateStatus <= InventorySelection.StatusDateEnd);
        }

        if (InventorySelection.CategoryID != 0)
            query = query.Where(q => q.CategoryID == InventorySelection.CategoryID);

        if (InventorySelection.BrandID != 0)
            query = query.Where(q => q.BrandID == InventorySelection.BrandID);

        if (InventorySelection.ModelID != 0)
            query = query.Where(q => q.ModelID == InventorySelection.ModelID);

        if (InventorySelection.EmployeeID != 0)
            query = query.Where(q => q.EmployeeID == InventorySelection.EmployeeID);

        if (InventorySelection.StatusID != 0)
            query = query.Where(q => q.StatusID == InventorySelection.StatusID);

        if (InventorySelection.EmployeeStatusID != 0)
            query = query.Where(q => q.EmployeeStatusID == InventorySelection.EmployeeStatusID);

        if (InventorySelection.CurrentLocationID != 0)
            query = query.Where(q => q.CurrentLocationID == InventorySelection.CurrentLocationID);
    }

    return query;
}
```

Comment: "Convert this into an async method" in what way?  What asynchronous operation are you trying to perform?  What did you try and what didn't work as expected?

Comment: A query is just an expression of intent. Any asynchronicity comes from the execution of the query, not the construction of it.

Comment: Unrelated: use `string.IsNullOrEmpty`. Small change but very convenient.

Comment: @David Well, it is doing DB so I thought it would be base async.

Comment: I'd probably consider a builder pattern with fluent api for that. But would depend on usage. I also created a `WhereIf` extension method on IQueryable, which also was quite handy.

Comment: @ChrisSchaller Maybe those last two lines will help?  I know that the data has been queried at that point as it is in the query variable.

Comment: Building the query is not async. Materializing it can be.

Comment: @Fildor, I appreciate the tip on the null or empty. I'm not sure on your other comment though.

Comment: If I remember tomorrow, I'll post an example. I'm on the cell phone right now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your query is being executed at the first line, I hope this is a typo, but `IEnumerable` is wrong as the variable type. It explicitly forces *ALL* of the records to be loaded into memory before any of your filters are applied. What you want is to *defer* the execution until all of the criteria have been defined.

```
IQueryable<T_IFS_Inventory> query = _db.T_IFS_Inventory.AsQueryable();
```

With only this change the query will be evaluated and the data will be returned as part of the return process. Because the method return type is `IEnumerable` the change from `IQueryable` to `IEnumerable` would force the evaluation as part of the return process.

To make this async, deliberately resolve the query:

```
return query.ToListAsync();
```

Or you can await it if you need this method's line info in the stack trace:

```
return await query.ToListAsync();
```

Both of these changes will require the method prototype to be made async too:

```
private async Task<IEnumerable<T_IFS_Inventory>> Getquery(T_IFS_InventorySelectDTO InventorySelection)
```

However now the method isn't getting a `query` it is now executing the entire query and bringing all of the data into memory.

A better approach that will allow you to compose on top of this query would be to change the method prototype to return `IQueryable`

```
private async IQueryable<T_IFS_Inventory> Getquery(T_IFS_InventorySelectDTO InventorySelection)
```

Ideally, your method should look like this:

```
private IQueryable<T_IFS_Inventory> Getquery(T_IFS_InventorySelectDTO InventorySelection)
{
    IQueryable<T_IFS_Inventory> query = _db.T_IFS_Inventory.AsQueryable();

    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(InventorySelection.SerialNumber))
    {
        query = query.Where(q => q.SerialNumber == InventorySelection.SerialNumber);
    }
    else
    {
        if (InventorySelection.ScanDateStart != null)
        {
            query = query.Where(q => q.ScanDate >= InventorySelection.ScanDateStart);

            if (InventorySelection.ScanDateEnd != null)
                query = query.Where(q => q.ScanDate <= InventorySelection.ScanDateEnd);
        }

        if (InventorySelection.StatusDateStart != null)
        {
            query = query.Where(q => q.DateStatus >= InventorySelection.StatusDateStart);

            if (InventorySelection.StatusDateEnd != null)
                query = query.Where(q => q.DateStatus <= InventorySelection.StatusDateEnd);
        }

        if (InventorySelection.CategoryID != 0)
            query = query.Where(q => q.CategoryID == InventorySelection.CategoryID);

        if (InventorySelection.BrandID != 0)
            query = query.Where(q => q.BrandID == InventorySelection.BrandID);

        if (InventorySelection.ModelID != 0)
            query = query.Where(q => q.ModelID == InventorySelection.ModelID);

        if (InventorySelection.EmployeeID != 0)
            query = query.Where(q => q.EmployeeID == InventorySelection.EmployeeID);

        if (InventorySelection.StatusID != 0)
            query = query.Where(q => q.StatusID == InventorySelection.StatusID);

        if (InventorySelection.EmployeeStatusID != 0)
            query = query.Where(q => q.EmployeeStatusID == InventorySelection.EmployeeStatusID);

        if (InventorySelection.CurrentLocationID != 0)
            query = query.Where(q => q.CurrentLocationID == InventorySelection.CurrentLocationID);
    }

    return query;
}
```

It is important when we use this query builder pattern that you keep the query as an `IQueryable` until all of the criteria have been added.

In terms of code style, I'd call this very clean, anything else is going to affect the readability, right now it's very easy to follow.

Comment: Mind that it is recommended and common practice to append "Async" to the method name and passing a cancellationtoken.

Comment: That's a very 1980s mindset. Unless you are going to implement both an _async_ and _non async_ version of this method then it is redundant information that is available by virtue of the response type being a `Task<>`. Yes there are common linting guidance that enforces this, but my goal is to keep the code clean and let my IDE give me hints when I need them. This method is also called `GetQuery` and now has two responsibilities, get the query and execute it to return the data. _Async_ in the name is the least concern.

Comment: @ChrisSchaller, getting closer but is says 'IEnumerable<T_IFS_Inventory>' does not contain a definition for 'ToListAsync'.  ToList works but is not async.

Comment: Since it is called "GetQuery" I'd actually return the IQueryable, yes. And then you can forget above convention.

Comment: @SteveCross I missed the fact that your variable was `IEnumerable`... It should be `IQueryable`! I've updated my response, please read it again from the top

Comment: Building an `IEnumerable` (or `IQueryable`) doesn't do anything. It's only when the caller enumerates the query that the whole table will be loaded. And it's the caller that would decide between running the query sync or async.

Comment: That is true if streaming is enabled, but not all configurations or implementations will use a _Data Reader_. The impact should still be considered, I'll reword it a bit.

Comment: Thank you, guys. This has been educational, and I appreciate your time.